# IntelliSense not working for omnisharp but for rest of extensions (e.g. F#)

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio-code, .net-core

### Environment data

`dotnet --info` output:

```
.NET Command Line Tools (2.0.3)

Product Information:
 Version:            2.0.3
 Commit SHA-1 hash:  12f0c7efcc

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  6.1.7601
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win7-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.3\

Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host

  Version  : 2.0.3
  Build    : a9190d4a75f4a982ae4b4fa8d1a24526566c69df
```

VS Code version:
C# Extension version:
`1.13.1`

### Steps to reproduce

It was working few weeks earlier properly however recently start failing to load intelliSense.

### Expected  behavior

Should show errors, missing reference, F12, should open definition of type.

### Actual behavior

Nothing working as expected.

### Screenshot: (No intelliSense error shown)

[image]

### Additional details:

User Settings

```
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite the default settings
{
    "http.proxyStrictSSL": false,
    "editor.minimap.enabled": true,
    "csharp.suppressDotnetInstallWarning": true,  
    "editor.multiCursorModifier": "ctrlCmd",
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
    "workbench.panel.location": "bottom",
    "gitlens.advanced.messages": {
        "suppressCommitHasNoPreviousCommitWarning": false,
        "suppressCommitNotFoundWarning": false,
        "suppressFileNotUnderSourceControlWarning": false,
        "suppressGitVersionWarning": false,
        "suppressLineUncommittedWarning": false,
        "suppressNoRepositoryWarning": false,
        "suppressUpdateNotice": false,
        "suppressWelcomeNotice": true
    },
    "gitlens.blame.line.enabled":true,
    "gitlens.codeLens.enabled":true,
    "gitlens.gitExplorer.enabled":true,
    "gitlens.statusBar.enabled": true,
    "FSharp.logLanguageServiceRequests": "both",
    "FSharp.logLanguageServiceRequestsOutputWindowLevel": "WARN",
    "csharp.format.enable": false
}
```

### Installed extensions:

[image]

> I tried to resolve issue by uninstalling & installing 2-3 times, no luck !

Comment: If you have found an answer to the question you should post it as an answer, not as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select Project /solution from status bar right bottom corner and it is started working like anything.

[image]